# How to remove unused CSS but keep comments?

Tags: css, optimization, stylesheet, code-cleanup

I know that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135657/tool-to-identify-unused-css-definitions) [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147441/firefox-addon-to-find-unused-css-styles) [has](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33242/how-can-i-find-unused-images-and-css-styles-in-a-website) [been](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10743314/unused-css-how-do-you-clean-it-up) [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7409980/detect-unused-css-rules) [multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7957881/tool-for-checking-unused-css-selectors) [times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650146/css-find-unused-css) [already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574136/how-do-i-identify-and-eliminate-unused-css-styles-from-my-bloated-stylesheet), but I still couldn't find a decent solution for my situation.

I have a *huge* CSS file, and about 50% of it is not being used at all in my current website. It also contains many valuable comments which I want to keep.

Due to the size of the CSS file, tools that can only identify the unused CSS definitions are not very helpful - I need a tool that can either *change* my unused definitions so I can apply regex to delete them afterwards, or *delete* the unused definitions for me, automatically.

[CSS Usage](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/css-usage/) does a great job changing all the unused definitions, and I can easily remove all of them with a regex - the problem is that CSS Usage also removes all the comments from my file, automatically.

**How can I remove all the unused definitions in my CSS file but keep all the comments?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can say i managed to do exactly what you are asking for, however it's not that neat!
in fact i modified on the extension code (i don't know if that's even acceptable round here :-D) but i know how to make you duplicate it :-) !

I commented this line in the extension code

```
/* CssUsage.js : 110 */
cssSource = cssSource.replace(/\/\*[\S\s]*?\*\//g, "");
```

It removes comments like `/* this is a comment */`

It gave me [this output](http://pastebin.com/StA9d2Dz)

anyway, if you want to duplicate this...
- [download the extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/downloads/latest/10704/addon-10704-latest.xpi?src=dp-btn-primary) (save to..)
- open the downloaded `.xpi` with any application like winrar
- edit `chrome/content/cssusage/CssUsage.js` and comment line 110
- drag it to firefox to reinstall

or just download this [xpi](http://www.mediafire.com/?0dz928d4vmoc8pe) and drag it to firefox to reinstall the extension!
maybe you can also try to make it remove the UNUSED lines using the regex you mentioned
`cssSource = cssSource.replace(/your regex/g, "");`

Comment: Great! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. The Regex I use [to remove UNUSED definitions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11918214/regex-to-match-any-unused-rules-in-css-class-id-etc) is `UNUSED.*\{[^}]*\}|UNUSED.*[}]*`

Comment: Nice! If you want, you can also write a review and ask the developer to add an option  for the comments :)